# How to scrape star ratings displayed as an image set as a background URL?

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

There are some websites that display different star ratings based on a single image set as background, for example: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004gHhLEAU

```
background: url(https://appexchange.salesforce.com/resource/1656544481000/assetsappx/images/appx-rating-stars.png) no-repeat 0 0;
```

How to scrape such rating values using Watir?

Comment: Looks like there is a CSS class on the element that corresponds with the rating: `appx-rating-stars appx-rating-stars-45` for 4.5 starts in this example.

Comment: This might be difficult as some will use different clipping regions to display the number of stars.  That's all done in the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @spickermann mentioned in the comments, the display of the rating image is controlled by the CSS classes. For example, the following has a "appx-rating-stars-45" class that creates the 4.5 star appearance:

```
<span id="appxListingDetailPageId:AppxLayout:j_id841:j_id842:j_id845" class="appx-rating-stars appx-rating-stars-45"></span>
```

To determine the star rating, we can retrieve this class and then parse the number:

```
star_rating_element = browser.div(class: 'appx-listing-detail').span(class: 'appx-rating-stars')
star_rating_raw = star_rating_element.class_name[/appx-rating-stars-(\d\d)/, 1]
#=> "45"
star_rating_value = star_rating_raw.to_i / 10.0
#=> 4.5
```

Comment: this makes sense, thanks. What if there was no number in the class name and you had to get the rating from the image?

Comment: It would depend on the exact implementation - ie what information is provided in the image itself. In this case, they don't provide anything in the image. Other sites might have separate images for each star rating so you could check the image file name. Or maybe the image would have a class that identifies the rating.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
require 'watir'

b=Watir::Browser.new :firefox

b.goto 'https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004gHhLEAU'

p b.element(xpath: "//p[normalize-space()='Rating']/../span/span/span[2]").text[/\((.*)\)/,1]
```

Output

```
"576"
```

Comment: Thanks @rajagopalan. Could you explain a bit what happened here? I'm very new to Ruby and Watir. Also, is there a non-xpath way of getting this info?

Comment: But can you please confirm me whether this is the output you would like to get?

Comment: Ah no, actually 576 is the reviews number. My question was about the star rating, so the value should be from 0 to 5.

Comment: Yes, but numbers are not displayed, yes? You are asking me to get the rating from the appearing stars?